# CSS remove linking at gaps where href comes from parent image

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an image which has a link. Then I have a round bullet images aligned inline that are placed over a parent image with link. When users tries to click on a bullet, sometimes they might miss small distance and click on image link (not bullet) accidentially. So I want those gaps that are between bullet points to have no link at all, but they still have link that comes from background.

Code is basic, like this:

```
<ul class="bullets2" style="position:relative;bottom:25px;left:50px">
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('CLICK BULLET')"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('CLICK BULLET')"></a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

There are also CSS style that you can look at code example.

An image below demonstrates what I want to achieve.
[image]

**And here is jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/RCkFL/

---

***UPDATE***

None of the solutions worked, so I used `<map>` combined with `<area>` Creating a polygon hotspot solved my problem. Thanks for all answers, anyways, I hope somebody will still come up with solution to my original question as CSS approach is way better. Thanks.

Comment: yes.. and I edited my question with "not-so-useful" solution. I'll be very much thankful if somebody will come up with css solution, please. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would place a  with the bullets on the image and would give that div a padding (for more "non-href"-space.

didn't try it, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you add some padding in your li tags that wrap around the bullets this should block the image link underneath.

CSS

```
ul.bullets2
{
    width:400px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom:40px;
    left:50px
}

ul.bullets2 li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul.bullets2 li a {
    background: url(http://s16.postimage.org/46ceaxz2p/bullet.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}

ul.bullets2 li a:hover, ul.bullets2 li a.selected
{
    background: url(http://s16.postimage.org/46ceaxz2p/bullet.png) no-repeat;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RCkFL/21/)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the post by 3dgoo, but slightly different ;)

Add padding to the images, set them as block, and set the 'li' to inline-block- there will be a 1 character space in between the items that does not trigger an image click.

```
ul.bullets2
{
    width:400px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.bullets2 li{
    display:inline-block;
}

ul.bullets2 li a {
    display:block;            
    background: url(http://s16.postimage.org/46ceaxz2p/bullet.png) no-repeat top center;
    padding:3px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}

ul.bullets2 li a:hover, ul.bullets2 li a.selected
{
    background: url(http://s16.postimage.org/46ceaxz2p/bullet.png) no-repeat center middle;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ev5q8/

Comment: From a UX perspective, this gives the user a larger space to click. Tiny buttons are frustrating! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.bullets2 {

    width: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;

}

ul.bullets2 li a {

    background: url('http://s16.postimage.org/46ceaxz2p/bullet.png') no-repeat;
    padding: 0px 8px;

}
```